# CSS triangle experiment

Tags: css

I can use the css triangle technique to add a point to one side of an object, and this works great with one item in isolation.

But I am looking to apply this to a list of items to show the direction of navigation (like so http://jsfiddle.net/jZcZK/2/).

What I want is replace the solid triangle arrow head with and linear arrow (like this >) - so just the right hand edge is showing.

Who's got a clever solution?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

does it work for you?
http://jsfiddle.net/kuyabiye/SJ9EK/

Comment: That's a great idea and would work well in a lot of scenarios. But I'm looking for something that's flexible enough for the item backgrounds to be css gradients.

Comment: I'm going with this as it's the cleanest solution - I'll just have to wait for browsers to support border-image gradients for it to work 100% how I'd like - but this is definately the way it should be done! http://jsfiddle.net/SJ9EK/9/

Comment: Great on that, @Colin.  One caveat: Not all browsers will support the :before and :after psdueo's.  You need to test it on all the browsers that your user is likely to use.

Comment: Yep I'm aware of that thanks. I'm happy for users on less advanced browsers to lose these features.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle is essentially a very thick border on only one side.

Put another "triangle" with the same color as your grey background on *top* of the original triangle, positioned just 1px to the left.  This should cover up your triangle leaving only a thin border.

Comment: This is the same as Berkin Berkcan Çırak's answer above isn't it?!

Comment: Yes.  He also gave an implementation, so pick his as the right answer.

Comment: Haha. I commented on why this doesn't work for me - although would be a great solution for a lot of people. I need something that is really 1px rather that the illusion of 1px.

Comment: Not without using a bitmap if you want it to work on all browsers (including IE).  For modern browsers, you can always use CSS transform to rotate a div by 45 degrees and have only a 1px border on the right/bottom sides.  This is how most JavaScript toolkits render the angled button style of iPhone.

Comment: And also, I don't understand.  The border can be made exactly 1 px wide -- it is not an illusion -- via positioning.  Is there any particular reason why @Berkin's solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: You can fill the insides with a gradient if you also fill the triangle border with the same gradient with CSS3 image borders...

Comment: Borders can have CSS gradients? If this is the case then that would work great. I can't produce a working example though.

Comment: I'm not sure this is currently possible. At least all the answers I'm reading about gradients in border-image say it doesn't work.

Comment: How about the bitmap of a gradient?  That should work for border images.  However, if you are using :before and :after pseudo's, then you are obviously not targetting IE.  Is there any reason why you can't use the CSS rotate transform trick?  It works on all WebKit browsers except FireFox 3.6 and below (unfortunately).

Comment: Yes I'm experimenting with this at the moment. Bit of a nightmare skewing the element so the border ends up 10px wide by 40px high - but I'm sure it can be done!

Comment: I'd advise against skewing the element.  Just rotate the div by 45 degrees, then scale it in one direction.  This will be much easier.

Comment: @Colin, rotate then scale, not scale then rotate.